# SQLite prepared statements re-planning

Tags: sqlite

Suppose I've prepared some statements with `sqlite3_prepare_v3`, after that I've inserted large amounts of data into database and run `ANALYZE`. Do I need to create the statements anew after that so that the query planner uses updated statistics information gathered by `ANALYZE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ANALYZE statement expires all prepared statements.
When you have used `sqlite3_prepare_v2()` or `_v3()`, the `sqlite3_step()` function will then automatically re-prepare the statement.